# Does a point of inflection of a function exist when it lies on the end of a closed interval?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I have a function which is bounded by a closed interval. I have worked out a point of inflection, however, it lies on one of the bounds of the interval. Does the inflection point exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function is restricted to the closed interval, there is no *other* side, so it's not an inflection point.

An inflection point is a point where the concavity *changes*, but if there's no other side, how could it change?

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks.